# electron-updater error in production New version is not signed by the application owner

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

After successfull checking for updates and downloading the latest, the updater shows error `New version 1.0.12 is not signed by the application owner: publisherNames: Cryptostamped LLC,`.

The error is present in production only (when the app is installed via `.exe` installer). No error in 'preview mode'.

The app is automatically signed using electron-builder, the `pack` script packages it and signs:

```
"pack": "yarn run build && yarn run rebuild && cross-env CSC_IDENTITY_AUTO_DISCOVERY=false electron-builder -c ./electron-builder.json --win"
```

I provided publisherName in my `electron-builder.json` config, and (just in case) wrote "publish" section.

```
"win": {
    "publisherName": "Cryptostamped LLC",
    "certificatePassword": "5947",
    "certificateFile": "./sign/certificate.pfx",
    "icon": "build/icons/icon.ico",
    "target": [
      {
        "target": "nsis",
        "arch": ["x64"]
      }
    ]
  },

  "publish": [
    {
      "provider": "generic",
      "url": "https://diana.crp.st/auto_updates/dev/",
      "publishAutoUpdate" : true
    }
  ],
```

Each version is signed with the same sertificate, `certificate.pfx`. The sertificate is self-signed via `openssl`, where `key.pem` and `cert.pem` is generated with this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -subj "//C=RU\L=Moscow\ST=Moscow\O=Cryptostamped\OU=Cryptostamped Moscow\emailAddress=office@cryptostamped.com\CN=Cryptostamped LLC"
```

and the sertificate file itself is generated with:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem
```

But anyway, the updater shows the error. Besides, the update process works fine when in "preview" mode (npm script named `preview`):

```
"preview": "yarn build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./app/",
```

In the installer properties, I see correct (I think) digital signing:
[image: signing table]
Here are details: [image: details of 1st sertificate]

Full error log here:

```
    Error: New version 1.0.12 is not signed by the application owner: publisherNames: Cryptostamped LLC, raw info: {
  "SignerCertificate": {
    "FriendlyName": "",
    "IssuerName": {
      "Name": "CN=Cryptostamped LLC, E=office@cryptostamped.com, OU=Cryptostamped Moscow, O=Cryptostamped, S=Moscow, L=Moscow, C=RU",
      "Oid": "System.Security.Cryptography.Oid"
    },
    "NotAfter": "/Date(1668700809000)/",
    "NotBefore": "/Date(1637164809000)/",
    "PrivateKey": null,
    "PublicKey": {
      "Key": "System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider",
      "Oid": "System.Security.Cryptography.Oid",
      "EncodedKeyValue": "System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData",
      "EncodedParameters": "System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData"
    },
    "SerialNumber": "234EE4A08FDCD1DBD8FBD434413D1B7D26FBE1B0",
    "SignatureAlgorithm": {
      "Value": "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11",
      "FriendlyName": "sha256RSA"
    },
    "Thumbprint": "1E7D49946DFF1C1B1430400178BBA5232F9B401B",
    "Version": 3,
    "Issuer": "CN=Cryptostamped LLC, E=office@cryptostamped.com, OU=Cryptostamped Moscow, O=Cryptostamped, S=Moscow, L=Moscow, C=RU",
    "Subject": "CN=Cryptostamped LLC, E=office@cryptostamped.com, OU=Cryptostamped Moscow, O=Cryptostamped, S=Moscow, L=Moscow, C=RU"
  },
  "TimeStamperCertificate": {
    "Archived": false,
    "Extensions": [
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageExtension",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509BasicConstraintsExtension",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension",
      "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension"
    ],
    "FriendlyName": "",
    "IssuerName": {
      "Name": "CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Timestamping CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
      "Oid": "System.Security.Cryptography.Oid"
    },
    "NotAfter": "/Date(1925424000000)/",
    "NotBefore": "/Date(1609459200000)/",
    "HasPrivateKey": false,
    "PrivateKey": null,
    "PublicKey": {
      "Key": "System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider",
      "Oid": "System.Security.Cryptography.Oid",
      "EncodedKeyValue": "System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData",
      "EncodedParameters": "System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData"
    },
    "SerialNumber": "0D424AE0BE3A88FF604021CE1400F0DD",
    "SubjectName": {
      "Name": "CN=DigiCert Timestamp 2021, O=\"DigiCert, Inc.\", C=US",
      "Oid": "System.Security.Cryptography.Oid"
    },
    "SignatureAlgorithm": {
      "Value": "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11",
      "FriendlyName": "sha256RSA"
    },
    "Thumbprint": "E1D782A8E191BEEF6BCA1691B5AAB494A6249BF3",
    "Version": 3,
    "Handle": 2005593979568,
    "Issuer": "CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Timestamping CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "Subject": "CN=DigiCert Timestamp 2021, O=\"DigiCert, Inc.\", C=US"
  },
  "Status": 1,
  "StatusMessage": "A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the **"verifyUpdateCodeSignature": false** to my electron-builder config file. it will solve the problem and everything works fine, as it skips the verification

```
"win": {
   "target": "nsis",
   "publisherName": "OneScreen LearningHub",
   "verifyUpdateCodeSignature": false 
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the signature CA is not trusted by the computer. You can fix by adding the certificate to the trusted users list as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/import-pfxcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps

You can also modify the signature verification function in `node_modules/electron-updater/out/windowsExecutableCodeSignatureVerifier.js` to not check for trusted hosts by removing this `if` block on line 50 and its closing bracket:

```
if (data.Status === 0) {
```

This will verify that the names match but it will not check if the root is a trusted authority by the computer.